# Unable to build React native project after upgrading to xcode 15. clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics, xcode15

After upgrading xcode to 15.0.1, Project is failing to build.

Below are the exact logs. It seems firebase analytics library but I am not sure what to do next. I did everything like pod deintegrate, pod install, delete pod file, reinstall node module etc..

Also attaching package.json file. May be any version issue. Please help!

I have Mac with M1 chip.

```
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++', '-lsqlite3', '-lz'
ld: warning: duplicate LC_RPATH are deprecated ('@executable_path/Frameworks')
ld: warning: duplicate LC_RPATH are deprecated ('@loader_path/Frameworks')
ld: warning: duplicate LC_RPATH are deprecated ('@executable_path/Frameworks')
ld: warning: duplicate LC_RPATH are deprecated ('@loader_path/Frameworks')
ld: warning: duplicate LC_RPATH are deprecated ('@executable_path/Frameworks')
ld: warning: duplicate LC_RPATH are deprecated ('@loader_path/Frameworks')
ld: warning: duplicate LC_RPATH are deprecated ('@executable_path/Frameworks')
ld: warning: duplicate LC_RPATH are deprecated ('@loader_path/Frameworks')
ld: warning: duplicate LC_RPATH are deprecated ('@executable_path/Frameworks')
ld: warning: duplicate LC_RPATH are deprecated ('@loader_path/Frameworks')
ld: warning: duplicate LC_RPATH are deprecated ('@executable_path/Frameworks')
ld: warning: duplicate LC_RPATH are deprecated ('@loader_path/Frameworks')
ld: warning: no platform load command found in '/Users/parth/Projects/projects/FA/rallie_rn/ios/Pods/MLKitBarcodeScanning/Frameworks/MLKitBarcodeScanning.framework/MLKitBarcodeScanning', assuming: iOS
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'CoreAudioTypes': framework 'CoreAudioTypes' not found
ld: Undefined symbols:
  _swift_getOpaqueTypeConformance, referenced from:
      associated type witness table accessor for SwiftUI.ViewModifier.Body : SwiftUI.View in FirebaseAnalytics.LoggedAnalyticsModifier : SwiftUI.ViewModifier in FirebaseAnalytics in FirebaseAnalytics[18](Analytics+SwiftUI.o)
  _swift_getTypeByMangledNameInContextInMetadataState, referenced from:
      ___swift_instantiateConcreteTypeFromMangledNameAbstract in libFirebaseCoreInternal.a[5](Heartbeat.o)
  _swift_stdlib_isStackAllocationSafe, referenced from:
      function signature specialization <Arg[1] = Owned To Guaranteed> of function signature specialization <Arg[0] = [Closure Propagated : reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_guaranteed (@unowned FirebaseCoreInternal.TimePeriod, @in_guaranteed Foundation.Date) -> (@unowned Swift.Bool, @error @owned Swift.Error) to @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed FirebaseCoreInternal.TimePeriod, @in_guaranteed Foundation.Date) -> (@unowned Swift.Bool, @error @owned Swift.Error), Argument Types : [@callee_guaranteed (@unowned FirebaseCoreInternal.TimePeriod, @in_guaranteed Foundation.Date) -> (@unowned Swift.Bool, @error @owned Swift.Error)]> of generic specialization <FirebaseCoreInternal.TimePeriod, Foundation.Date> of Swift._NativeDictionary.filter(((key: A, value: B)) throws -> Swift.Bool) throws -> Swift._NativeDictionary<A, B> in libFirebaseCoreInternal.a[6](HeartbeatController.o)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

```
{
  "name": "ReactNativeTemplateV2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^8.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.0.9",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.4.1",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^3.0.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^14.9.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.9.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^14.9.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.7",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.3.13",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.7.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "base64-string": "^1.1.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "form-data": "^2.3.3",
    "geolib": "^3.3.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "pod-install": "^0.1.39",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-inverted-scrollview": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native": "0.63.3",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-autogrow-textinput": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-branch": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-card-stack-swiper": "^1.2.5",
    "react-native-cardview": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-code-push": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-contacts": "^7.0.4",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-deck-swiper": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-device-info": "^5.6.3",
    "react-native-draggable-flatlist": "^2.5.4",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^4.0.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-emoji-selector": "^0.1.9",
    "react-native-event-listeners": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-exception-handler": "^2.10.10",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.2",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.1.16",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.0-beta.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-get-location": "^1.4.3",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.10.3",
    "react-native-image-slider": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-keep-awake": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-view": "0.0.14",
    "react-native-localize": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-location": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-map-clustering": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-material-menu": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.10.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^5.0.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.7.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.4",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.4.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-scalable-image": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-swipeable": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.16.0",
    "react-native-toasty": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-tracking-transparency": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.0.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^10.3.3",
    "rn-range-slider": "^2.0.4",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.10.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.5.0",
    "jest": "^26.1.0",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.61.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Tried pod deintegrate, reinstall pods, reinstall node packages, clean build folder.